# AVAudioPlayer crash after updating to xCode 4.6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

After updating to xCode 4.6 my audio player crashes with no error logs. I cannot log the error as it crashes on play. I get no message on the debugger only a thread/ breakpoint on play.Anyone any ideas?

```
NSError *error;
NSString *stringPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath1];
playerForRecording = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1 error:&error];
[playerForRecording setDelegate:self];
[playerForRecording play];
```

http://i1107.photobucket.com/albums/h385/snksnk1/stack%20overflow/ScreenShot2013-02-05at54421PM_zps72842a8f.png

Comment: Try checking if the player is nil before calling its methods

Comment: Cleaning the project sometimes work for these strange errors. For xCode 4.6 you hit *Command + K* to perform the clean action...Might not solve your problem but worth a shot.

Comment: Already tried cleaning the project and did check and player is not nil.. added a photo for you to see.. thanks

Comment: try re-adding AVFoundation framework

Comment: Do you have a break point set for all Exceptions? If so, try turning it off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same compiler and this works for me:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *stringPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath1];
NSAssert(url1, @"URL is valid.");
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1 error:&error];
if(!self.player)
{
    NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
}
[self.player play];
```

Of course, in the .h, are the lines:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface myProgramViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer* player;
```

with, in the .m, the corresponding:

```
@synthesize player = mPlayer;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: already tried to clean my project and triple checked my header file. Still crashes.. tried with and without delegate declaration. added screen capture for you to see

Comment: Did you try an `NSLog` of the error variable?  (I added an edit just now.)

Comment: A couple of things come to mind... Is beep.mp3 included in your project (and member of your target)? Also, try `NSURL* url1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"beep" withExtension:@"mp3"];` (instead of the 2nd and 3rd lines) and `NSAssert(url1, @"URL is valid.");` (where I edited my code).